# Given the characteristic polynomial of $T^2-3T + 3Id$, find that of $T$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T: V \rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation, wherein $\dim(V)=4$.
Suppose it is known that the characteristic polynomial of $T^2 - 3T + 3Id$ is $\lambda^4$. Is it possible to deduce the characteristic polynomial of $T$?

I have the slight inkling that the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem might be of some use, but as to how to proceed with it, I am not wholly certain.

Answer (score 3):

First, what are the roots of $x^2-3x+3$? This has no real roots, as the polynomial has negative discriminant. This means that $x^2-3x+3$ is irreducible over $\Bbb R$ and $(x^2-3x+3)^4$ annihilates $T$ (this is the Cayley-Hamilton theorem). Now, the minimal polynomial of $T$ divides the characteristic polynomial of $T$, which in turn divides a power of the minimal polynomial of $T$. But the degree of the characteristic polynomial of $T$ is $\dim V = 4$. This means we have no choice for powers and the characteristic polynomial of $T$ is $(x^2-3x+3)^2$.

Comment: Thank you for your response; however, I have not yet learnt of minimal polynomials and annihilation... Do you know any other way by which to deduce the characteristic polynomial of $T$?

Comment: Saying that $p(x)$ annihilates $T$ is jargon for $p(T)=0$. So the content of the Cayley-Hamilton theorem is that the characteristic polynomial of $T$ annihilates $T$. The minimal polynomial of $T$ is the monic polynomial with the smallest degree that annihilates $T$. There's all there is to it.